# Difference between open and override methods in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

```
open class Base {

    open fun v() {}

    fun nv() {}
}

class Derived() : Base() {

    override fun v() {}
}
```

This is an example. Can someone please explain the difference?
Is open keyword mandatory here?

Comment: why do you tag this with Java? you may want to check this: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Yes, both `open` keywords are mandatory in your example.

---

You have to distinguish between the use of `open` on classes and functions.

**Class:** You need the `open` keyword on a class if you want to inherit from it. By default all classes are `final` and can not be inherited from.

**Function:** On a function you need `open` to be able to override it. By default all functions are `final` and you cannot override them.

---

**Edit:** Because I saw some confusion in the comments.

> I have an internal abstract class which I can Inherit without any
> problem. I also can override it abstract methods as I please without
> declaring them as open

Abstract classes are meant to be inherited because you cannot instantiate them. in fact they are not just `open` by default, they cannot be `final` in the first place. `final` and `abstract` are not compatible. The same goes for `abstract` methods, they have to be overriden!

Comment: But what about 'public' keyword? Can I inherit from 'public class'?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko "If you do not specify any visibility modifier, public is used by default, which means that your declarations will be visible everywhere." https://kotlinlang.org/docs/visibility-modifiers.html `public` on a class has nothing to do with inheritance though.

Answer (score 3):

By default, the functions in Kotlin are defined as `final`.
That means you cannot override them. If you remove the `open` from your function `v()` than you will get an error in your class `Derived` that the function `v` is final and cannot be overridden.

When you mark a function with `open`, it is not longer `final` and you can override it in derived classes.

Answer (score 2):

> The `open` annotation on a class is the opposite of Java's `final`: it allows others to inherit from this class as by default all classes in Kotlin are `final`. [[Source](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html)]

Only after declaring a class as `open` we can `inherit` that class.

A method can only be `overridden` if it is open in the base class. Annotation `override` signals the overriding of base method by inheriting class.