# Simple inheritance example in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

In Java I have these two classes :

```
public class Base {
    protected Long id;
    // getter setter
}
public User extends Base {
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
    public User(Long id) { this.id = id; }
    // getter setter
}
```

I created these two classes in Kotlin :

```
open class Base(var id: Long? = null)
class User(
        var id: Long? = null,
        var name: String? = null,
        var age: Int? = null
) : Base()
```

Now in Java I want to call the User() constructor with only the 'id' parameter :

```
new User(5);
```

This seems wrong to me, because by doing this I re-declared the "id" field in the User class.

How can I set the id field of the base class in Kotlin (like I did in Java with "this.id = id;" ?

Comment: Please edit first snippet, make `User extends Base`

Comment: Done. I didn't copy paste the code and forgot to add it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, your Kotlin code would not compile, because you would get the following error: `Error:'id' hides member of supertype 'Base' and needs 'override' modifier`.

Basically, the compiler would also complain that you redeclared `id` from `Base`, in `User`.

If you want to redeclare it, you need to first make `id` [open](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#overriding-properties) in `Base`, and then in `User`, you need to use the [override](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#overriding-properties) keyword, when redeclarding `id`. (also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46399430/difference-between-open-and-override-methods-in-kotlin?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa))

Furthermore, for the Kotlin compiler to generate overloads of the `User` constructor, you need to annotate your primary constructor with [@JvmOverloads](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-overloads/). Without @JvmOverloads, you wouldn't be able to use the `User(id)` constructor (just `id` as param) in Java, and would have to specify all 3 parameters.

So your code would become:

```
open class Base(open var id: Long? = null)

class User @JvmOverloads constructor(override var id: Long? = null,
                                     var name: String? = null,
                                     var age: Int? = null
) : Base(id)
```

Now, if you don't want to redeclare `id` in User, you can simply not use `var` in front of it, and instead pass it directly to `Base`, when calling its constructor. So basically this:

```
open class Base(var id: Long? = null)

class User @JvmOverloads constructor(id: Long? = null,
                                     var name: String? = null,
                                     var age: Int? = null
) : Base(id)
```

Comment: I left out @JvmOverloads just to see what happens and got a compile time error. With the annotation everything works as expected. Thanks for the thorough explanation !

Comment: With pleasure! The @JvmOverloads just allows you to use the `User(id)` constructor in Java, instead of `User(id, name, age)`. One annoying thing about @JvmOverloads though is that you cannot use it in Kotlin interfaces, although methods in Kotlin interfaces can have default parameters. This can yield surprises when the interface is used from Java, but they're easy to fix by overloading the method in the interface itself.

Comment: Why can't we declare the member as `abstract` instead of `open`?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your code will give the error: `'id' hides member of supertype 'Base' and needs 'override' modifier` when you try to run it.
This is because when kotlin compiler sees `var id: Long? = null` it will try to create a variable with name `id` and type `Long?`. But due to inheritance it would have already had `id` variable in its scope.
So the compiler will complain you to **either access the variable or create it and hence the above error**.

Now to answer your question: `How can I set the id field of the base class in Kotlin`
You can do that by:

```
open class Base(var id: Long?=null)
class User(
        id: Long?=null,
        var name: String? = null,
        var age: Int? = null
) : Base(id)
```

Here in the above code, what I did is I have overridden the `id` variable in the child class constructor `User`. So this `id` variable can take any `Long` type value (that we will pass while calling the `User` class constructor) or `null` as the default value.
After that I have just passed this new value to `Base` class by `Base(id)` that is same as doing `this.id = id` in java.

Hope this answer is helpful.

Answer (score -1):

I believe it's simply a matter of passing the ID to the constructor of the superclass

```
open class Base(var id: Long? = null)
class User(
    var id: Long? = null,
    var name: String? = null,
    var age: Int? = null
) : Base(id)
```

Comment: Would not compile. Error would be: `'id' hides member of supertype 'Base' and needs 'override' modifier`.

Comment: That should teach me to test my snippets in a scratch file. Thanks for the explanation